# Write a generic method for derived classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract BaseClass from which multiple derived classes are inherited.
I want to write a generic method that does a common work, so that I dont need to write that method for every derived class.

Current Code -

```
  public abstract class BaseClass{}


    public class Derived1 : BaseClass{
      public Derived1 CommonWork(){

      /* Common work */
      return objDerived1;
      }

}

 public class Derived2 : BaseClass{
      public Derived2 CommonWork(){

      /* Common work */
      return objDerived2;
      }

}
```

The way I want -

```
public T CommonWork where T : BaseClass

{
/* Common work */
return T;

}
```

Now I dont know how and where to write this method. Coudnt find it anywhere else.
Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like that:

```
public class CommonWork<T> 
  where T: BaseClass,
           new T()// <- probably you'll need it to create instances of T

  public T CommonWork(){
    T result = new T();
    ...

    return T;
  }
}

...

Commonwork<Derived2> common = new Commonwork<Derived2>();

BaseClass result = common.CommonWork();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would define it in the `BaseClass` and include the generic argument in your method declaration:

```
public T CommonWork<T>() where T : BaseClass {
  T returnObj;
  returnObj = default(T);  // To initialize a new instance
  returnObj = this as T;   // To operate on the current object

  /* Common work */ 

  return returnObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var derived1=new Derived1();
            derived1.CommonWork();

            var derived2 = new Derived2();
            derived2.CommonWork();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public string ClassName;

        public T CommonWork<T>(T obj)
        {
            var baseClass = obj as BaseClass;
            Console.WriteLine( baseClass.ClassName);
            return obj;
        }


    }

    public class Derived1 : BaseClass
    {
        public Derived1 CommonWork()
        {
            this.ClassName = "Derived1";
          return  this.CommonWork(this);            
        }

    }

    public class Derived2 : BaseClass
    {
        public Derived2 CommonWork()
        {
            this.ClassName = "Derived2";
           return this.CommonWork(this);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the common work is done in the base class but the method returns the derived class object:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T: BaseClass<T>, new()
{
    public int Value { get; private set; } 
    public T CommonWork()
    {
        var result = new T {Value = 1};
        return result;
    }
}

public class Derived1 : BaseClass<Derived1>
{
}

public class Derived2 : BaseClass<Derived2>
{
}
```

You call it this way:

```
Derived2 derived2 = new Derived2();
Derived2 anOtherderived2 = derived2.CommonWork();
int value = anOtherderived2.Value; // 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works with a single level of inheritance, since there's no way a class `SubDerived1` can inherit from both `Derived1` and `BaseClass<SubDerived1>`.  One could, however, define a covariant interface and have each type implement it upon itself.  If ones explicit implementation but includes an extension method which operates on the interface, it may be possible to achieve the proper semantics (having each thing's `CommonWork` return an object of proper type).

Comment: @supercat You are right. But the OP didn't asked for more then one level in his example. If he need more levels, then your option might be a solution.